# python recursion return issue

Tags: python, recursion

Could you please explain to me why I can't catch return event in this case ??

```
s1 = "(){}[]"
s2 = "([{}])"
s3 = "(}"
s4 = "[(])"
s5 = "[({})]((]"

def validBraces(string):
    lst = ['()','{}','[]']
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        braces = string[i]+ string[i+1]
        if braces in lst:
               validBraces(string[:i]+string[i+2:])



    if len(string) == 0:
        print("True")
        return True

    return False

print (validBraces(s1))
```

So it's going to pass every time the return event, what is wrong here ? 
So, I can print "True" but cant stop it and return True.....

Comment: do you need to return `validBraces(string[:i]+string[i+2:])`?

Comment: A `return` statement doesn't generate an event.  What "events" do you think you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, I need stop and return True if len == 0

Comment: When you call `validBraces` recursively, you need to `return` the result.  Instead, you're dropping it on the floor, completely ignoring the recursive call.  It's as if you never made the call (except for perhaps printing "True" in the call for debugging).

Comment: try printing `i` and `i+1` in each iteration of the for loop and see what happens

Comment: heh...being downvoted for unpythonic code... easy there, folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following incorporates Tom's answer, along with a complete test and other improvements.

```
s1 = "(){}[]"
s2 = "([{}])"
s3 = "(}"
s4 = "[(])"
s5 = "[({})]((]"

def validBraces(string):
    lst = ['()','{}','[]']
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        braces = string[i:i+2]
        if braces in lst:
            return validBraces(string[:i]+string[i+2:])

    return not string

for s in (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
    print (validBraces(s))
# should be True, True, False, False, False
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot about "return recursion" !!! And there is no drama like comments above